# How to record http interactions in ruby vcr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stubbing, vcr

I am working in Rails project which uses below gems.

```
gem "webmock", "1.6.1"
gem "vcr", "1.4.0"
```

Already few http interactions are recorded in test_data.yml. I have implemented new business logic and I tried to record the http interactions. But its not recording. Below are the VCR configurations I used.

```
VCR.config do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir     = File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'helpers', 'cassette_library')
  c.http_stubbing_library    = :webmock
  c.ignore_localhost         = false
end
VCR.insert_cassette('test_data', :record => :new_episodes)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [VCR record modes](https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/1-6-0/docs/record-modes). With `:record => :new_episodes`, VCR is replaying previously recorded requests. While making changes in logic, you can try deleting your previously recorded requests or switching to record mode `:all`.

Comment: Is it also recording the requests even if the url is the same?